# getting resource id #5 printed.dont know what is the solution

Tags: php, mysql

```
$u=$_SESSION['username'];
$p=$_SESSION['password'];
$a = mysql_query("SELECT section FROM users WHERE username ='$u' AND password ='$p'");
echo "$a";
```

getting resource id #5 printed.dont know what is the problem?

Comment: DB connection...selecting the schema....?

Comment: Check the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php , see first example you`ll get it

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) doesn't return a string.

Comment: _“dont know what is the problem?”_ – problem is you did not read up on the absolute basics first. Please read a tutorial or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries return resource objects. You need to loop over the resource to fetch each record.

Taken from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

**Note:** The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).